# How to make 'perishable' link in Tornado

Tags: validation, tornado

i want to make a link that is valid only for 24 hours, this is for a validation purpose, so my question is simple:

How do i make this link valid only for this time; i've a hint:

1. Get the epoch time.
2. Make a link using only this value: something.com/time/1359380374
3. When the user clics on the link, extract this value and compare.

I hear about Hash values? why? we cant get the time from the hash value (invert the process) so how this is done?

Comment: Are you storing this link inside a database? Because you can use the route `"/time/(\w+)"` in your application and search the database for the valid link, and if expired, then send back a `tornado.web.HTTPError`.

Comment: but the access to database will cost another fetch, so why not making a simple cpu operation (comparaison with a calculated value)

Comment: Does the link redirect to somewhere else? ex. something.com/1359380374/my_redirect_url_escaped I'm a little confused what you will do with this url so I can help you figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: thank you :D what am trying to do is: validating an account: the first time the users opens a new acount, and the next time he forgets the password to reset his old one and let the application generate a temporary password.

Comment: I see no harm in asking the database with a simple query to see if the account is valid: `select is_locked, locked_expire from users where email = '$email' limit 1`. But I will post an answer to your question below.

Comment: so then i must create tables for expired links? so then the server must make a request for the database when the link expires (kind of a trigger)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23642/discussion-between-steve-peak-and-abdelouahab-pp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to have the users email send as an argument and then query the database to see if their link has expired:

**Requested link query**: `update users set locked_stamp = now();`

**Request url**: `http://yourdomain.com/?email=useremail`

**Query**: `select true from users where email = '$email' and locked_stamp > now()-interval 1 hour and now() limit 1`

**Result**: You have a person requesting within the hour with email: `$email`.

---

I have a script that using base64 to encode the timestamp... but its not secure by any means.

```
import tornado.web
import base64, re, time
import sys

def get_time():
    """Method used to get the current time in b64"""
    return base64.b64encode(str(int(time.mktime(time.localtime()))))

class WebHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, _time):
        timecheck = base64.b64decode(_time)
        try:
            #require it to be all digits
            assert re.match('^\d+$', timecheck) is not None
            # Must be within 1 hour: greater then 1 hour ago and less then now
            assert int(timecheck) > int(time.mktime(time.localtime()))-3600 and \
                int(timecheck) < int(time.mktime(time.localtime()))
        except AssertionError:
            raise tornado.web.HTTPError(401,'Woops! Unauthorized.')
        else:
            self.write('Pass')


# Route
application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/([^\/]+)/?", WebHandler),
])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8889)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: that's what i need, thank you :) but, why using BASE64, is it to not let the user forge its date?

Comment: Base64 would only *discourage* some from figuring out how you system operates. If they figure out the technique of you encoding the simple timestamp in base64 then it defeats the purpose of encoding it in the first place. You can always use a different technique that will allow you to, for more or less, be more secure (ex. http://code.google.com/p/python-simpleencode/). However, I still recommend hitting the database and storing the timestamp there. Thanks.

Comment: thank you! am learning :D, i just tried Facebook system and exactly what you said: facebook.com/recover/code?u=user-id&n=the-validation-code

Comment: i'll use base64.urlsafe_b64encode() since it will avoir / for example.
thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

the same way it sets secure cookies:

```
signed_message = self.create_signed_value(secret, name, value)
```

Then you can check it:

```
message = self.decode_signed_value(secret, name, value, max_age_days=31, clock=None,min_version=None)
```

Secret should be a long random number, but you only need one per app. min_version could be DEFAULT_SIGNED_VALUE_VERSION (which is currently 2).

Don't roll your own solution. Use the one in the library. It's there. It works.